# Flutter Family Tree Creating Widget

Tags: json, flutter, plugins, android-graphview, family-tree

I am searching for a **Flutter** plugin which can help in building a *Family Tree* exactly what it has to be and it needs to build dynamically from a raw JSON. I found some plugins but those are not I am expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am answering my own question. Recently I found a **Flutter Plugin** [graphview](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview), using this we are able to create a family tree but need some work to build it dynamically from a raw JSON.

Comment: hey, can you please share the code how you generate tree from JSON?